# jsPDF autotable color in header and center text in rows

Tags: javascript, pdf, colors, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to manipulate Autotable jsPDF, but I can't help but generate my pdf with default styles. I try the methods that I have read on various sites, but they are all outdated, and have changed several times.
I would like to add a title at the beginning of the table that is centered (outside of it), add color to the table headings, and maybe paste a signature below it. I have tried various modes and the only way I can print a PDF without dying on the way is like this. I've tried manipulating it from css but it doesn't take my changes.

```
    function generatePdf() {
    var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({html: '.tftable'});
    doc.save ("detallePrestamo.pdf");

}
generatePdf()
```

Answer (score 4):

I make this solution, comments on each line so that it is understood what each property does and how it should be written

```
function generatePdf() {
    var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
    var offsetY = 4.797777777777778; //var offsetY is for spacing
    var lineHeight = 6.49111111111111; //var lineHeight is for Spacing
    var fontSize = 12;
    doc.text(85, 10, "Tabla de Prestamo");//asignate coordinates to the title
    doc.autoTable({startY: 15,html: '.tftable', styles : { halign : 'center'}, headStyles :{fillColor : [124, 95, 240]}, alternateRowStyles: {fillColor : [231, 215, 252]}, tableLineColor: [124, 95, 240], tableLineWidth: 0.1,}); //use headStyles to bring styles to the table head, and alternateRowStyles to color the rows but one yes and one no
    doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
    var img = new Image(); //this mount a variable to img
    img.src = 'images/signaturePDF.png' //asign the src to the img variable
    doc.addImage(img, 'png', 100, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + lineHeight * 1.5 + offsetY, 20, 20)// use the method doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + lineHeight * 1.5 + offsetY to be able to position the image of the signature below the table at a safe distance from it 
    doc.text(90, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + lineHeight * 5 + offsetY, "Juan Jose Urquiza") // later add the text below the signature
    doc.text(89, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + lineHeight * 6 + offsetY, "Gerente FinanceAR") //more text
    doc.save ("detallePrestamo.pdf");

}
```

and that are my result in image[image: image that shows the signature, and the two text blocks later positioning the text below it]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

To help clarify @user16754567 answer above:

Based on the initial question which was asked on how to add color in header and center the table. The code below explains it.

var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({
headStyles : {fillColor : [124, 95, 240]}, //This will change the header colour, feel free to change to rgb values to suite your need.
alternateRowStyles: {fillColor : [231, 215, 252]} //This is used to add colours in your rows
});

for more info regarding jpdf, check out these links:

2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMeeWIIZGQ8.
3. https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-jspdf-autotable-tutorial/